# red line hover effect on navigation javascript

Tags: javascript, navigation

i have a main navigation on the header and a footer navigation. But i will only have main navigation on the Header and the footer navigation to put out. But if put out the footer navigation, the main navigation "red line" hover effect doesn't work because the main navigation related with the footer navigation and i don't know whats the problem..

Here my Testsite:

http://topkosmetikstudios.de/release/index.php?article_id=1

here my javascript Code:

```
function header_menu_line() {
    "use strict";
    var $el, leftPos, newWidth;
    $("#magic-line").remove();
    $("#main_menu").append("<li id='magic-line'></li>");
    var $magicLine = $("#magic-line");
    $magicLine
        .width($(".current_menu_ancestor").width())
        .css("left", $(".current_menu_ancestor a").position().left)
        .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left)
        .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
    $("#main_menu > li").hover(function() {
        $el = $(this).find("a");
        leftPos = $el.position().left;
        newWidth = $el.parent().width();
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: leftPos,
            width: newWidth
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $magicLine.stop().animate({
            left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
            width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
        }, 300);    
    });
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear, you want to remove footer navigation completely?

Comment: Yep. But if i remove footer navigation completely then the main navigation red line hover effect doesn't work :( and i don't know why do it so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check where you are targeting .current_menu_ancestor, you are using that class in the footer as well and you aren't targeting specifically for the header; something there might be throwing it.

Comment: Great! Is it appropriate to accept this answer as the solution?

Comment: Yes. How can i do that? I'm new here

Comment: You click the checkmark next to the answer and it will turn green. Thanks.